# Socket.io server doesn't receive messages

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm trying to follow the official socket.io tutorial but I can't get the server to receive messages. I've spent a few hours trying all sorts of things. I'm completely out of ideas.

Here's the server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //socket.emit('greeting', 'welcome to the chat');
    socket.on('chat', function (msg) {
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

and the client:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            font: 13px Helvetica, Arial;
        }

        form {
            background: #000;
            padding: 3px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

            form input {
                border: 0;
                padding: 10px;
                width: 90%;
                margin-right: .5%;
            }

            form button {
                width: 9%;
                background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
                border: none;
                padding: 10px;
            }

        #messages {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

            #messages li {
                padding: 5px 10px;
            }

                #messages li:nth-child(odd) {
                    background: #eee;
                }
    </style>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        //localStorage.debug = '*';
        var socket = io("http://localhost:3000/");
        socket.on('greeting',
            function (msg)
            {
                console.log(msg);
            }
            );
        /*
        $('form').submit(function ()
        {
            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
            //$('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });
        */
        $("#sendBtn").click(function ()
        {
            socket.emit('chat', $('#m').val());
            return false; 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button id="sendBtn">Send</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The client can receive messages from the server but the other way around doesn't work. I've tried turning on debugging but I can't tell if what I'm seeing is right or wrong. However, there certainly is an interaction happening when I press send on the webpage.

Here's how it looks from the client side:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct the bind to your element, and you are trying to bind to a component that isn't rendered yet. You need to wait for DOM to be ready. Try this.

```
$(function() {
    $("#sendBtn").on('click', function ()
    {
        socket.emit('chat', $('#m').val());
        return false;
    });
});
```

Wrapping your function like this you are telling to execute only when the page is loaded

Comment: Wow. I did not see that! Thank you so much, Eduardo!